# Creating two types of user

Tags: android, mysqli, android-sqlite

I'm very new to programming and I'm writing to ask for help for my application. I'm using android studio 2.3.

I'm trying to create an app where there are two types of users which is **high committee** and **non-high committee**. The difference between both types of users is that the high committee has an additional activity which the non-high committee doesn't have.

*High committee able to: Login, View calendar, Add/Update event*

*Non-high committee able to: Login, View calendar*

However, I don't know how to create a login activity that allows these types of users to login in the same login screen using username and password and how to make these users to have a different Homepage.

I'd really appreciate any help with this, thanks in advance.

I have this code here below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            // Response received from the server
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeCalendar.class);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the usertype also, along with the server response and check the received usertype in your java code and then redirect to the corresponding home activity.

Below is a code sample. Please check it..

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        String user_type = jsonResponse.getString("user_type"); //get user_type from response

                        if (success) {
                            if(user_type.equals("high_committee")){ //check the type of user
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeCommittee.class); //if user_type = committee, then redirect to Committee home activity
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else{
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeNonCommittee.class); //if user_type != committee, then redirect to Committee home activity
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```